# Where to go to get my story critiqued?

Tags: short-story, criticism

I have recently completed a short story work of mine. I have published it on Wattpad, and I've sent the Google Docs link of it to several friends.
I am kind of new to writing in general, and Wattpad is my idea of a large user-base literature platform.
What are some other platforms I could use to have my work read by others?

Comment: Have you looked for online sites? Writers.com, critique.org? Others....?

Answer (score 5):

Check out your local library, community center or bookstore to see if there is a local writers group in your area.  You can also look on Meetup.com.
Most writing group have a critique-circle feature where you trade honest critical feedback (and occasionally honest praise) with other local amateur writers.

If you live in a major city or population center, you will probably have several groups to choose from.  In that case, look for a group which focuses on your genre and target audience age.

Answer (score 5):

There are many major Internet forums that have critique groups.  I've used several of them -- starting with [Orson Scott Card's hatrack.com](http://www.hatrack.com/writers/index.shtml), continuing at [Forward Motion](http://fmwriters.com/zoomfm/index.php/home) and [Absolute Write](https://absolutewrite.com/forums/forum.php).  I've had useful critiques at all of them.

I'd suggest in looking for a group you should have a look at what you think of not just the quality of the critiques but also the quality and type of writing that's being posted there, and whether any of the regular contributors are either professional writers or clearly have the attitude and determination to get there. (Anecdote: when I was using the hatrack.com site regularly, one of our other members was [Mary Robinette Kowal](http://maryrobinettekowal.com/), and it was *easy* to see how good she was even back then before she was published)